# The problem is when I click on the link in the Navbar it doesn't go to its section

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic navbar and when I click on the link it goes to its specific section and I used the following code:

```
//scroll to section when click on nav links
    li_links.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        section.scrollIntoView()
    });
```

Why when I click on the link it goes to the end of the page and not to the specified section?

This is the code:

```
const Ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
for(section of sections) {
    //create li:
    const li_items = document.createElement("li");
    
    //create new anchor elements:
    const li_links = document.createElement("a");
    
    //give anchor elements a hyperlinks:
    const IdAttribute = section.getAttribute('id');
    li_links.setAttribute('href', IdAttribute);

    //get the names of the sections:
    const navData = section.getAttribute("data-nav");
    const text = document.createTextNode(navData);
    
    //give the navbar style :
    li_links.classList.add("menu__link");

    Ul.appendChild(li_items);
    li_items.appendChild(li_links);
    li_links.appendChild(text);

    //scroll to section when click on nav links
    li_links.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        section.scrollIntoView()
    });

}
//end of the navbar.
```

HTML Code:

```
<header id="hdr" class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
      <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

code on codepen:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/atdv1164/pen/GRmvEKV)

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I have put the html code

Comment: I think what is giving you problems is `for(section of sections)`; try replacing it with `for(let section of sections)`, in order to avoid creating a global variable which might conflict with something that is already existing

Comment: @secan Thank you very much it is working now.

Comment: If you want to be extra sure and not relying on the browser ability to understand what you actually mean, you might want to replace `li_links.setAttribute('href', IdAttribute);` with `li_links.setAttribute('href', '#' + IdAttribute);` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `const` or `let` to declare a block scoped variable

```
for(const section of sections) {
```

Otherwise the `section` is in the function scope, and it is re-assigned for each iteration of the loop. So when the events happen they will point to the last value of `section`.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description